# Creating a new entry with preset values

Tags: grails

Solved. I really don't know what I did, but it worked. One of those moments...

My domain object is "Actiune". I want to add a new entry with 4 preset fields from another entry that has the given id to "createNewEtapa" method. So I query that entry (with the id) and get it's values, preset them in the form and the hit save but it does not work. The save will not work.

What am I doing wrong ? I've been going around this for hours. Please help again stackOverflow :)

If you don't feel like checking all the code, please just let me know how is this done or link me a example :)

Thx!

**These are the relevalt parts of my code**

**This is my GSP form:**

```
<g:form action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <fieldset class="form">

                    <g:applyLayout name="form">
                        <tmpl:/templates/form />
                    </g:applyLayout>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="buttons">

                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save"
                        value="${message(code: 'default.button.adauga.label', default: 'Adauga')}" />
                    <g:actionSubmit name="create" class="save" action="savenew" value="Adauga2" />

                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
def create(Long id){
def actiuneInstance = Actiune.findById(id)
def c = Actiune.createCriteria()
def instanceList = c {
    eq("idActiune", actiuneInstance.idActiune)
    order("termenPornire", "asc")
}

params.idActiune = actiuneInstance.idActiune
params.tema = actiuneInstance.tema
params.firma = actiuneInstance.firma
params.user = User.findById(springSecurityService.currentUser.id)

[instance: new Actiune(params)]
}

def save() {
def actiuneInstance = new Actiune(params)
actiuneInstance.user = User.findById(springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
actiuneInstance.termenPornire = new Date()

def actiuneBD = Actiune.findByIdActiune(params.idActiune)
actiuneInstance.idActiune = actiuneBD.idActiune
actiuneInstance.tema = actiuneBD.tema
actiuneInstance.firma = actiuneBD.firma

print "in params  " + params
print "\\"
print "in save...       " + actiuneInstance.properties

   if (!actiuneInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [firInstance: actiuneInstance])
        return
    }
flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'actiune.label', default: 'Actiune'), actiuneInstance.idActiune])
redirect(action: "completeShow", id: actiuneInstance.id)
}
```

**This is the output from the print statements in the save() method**
**...**
in params  [termenLimita_month:11, termenPornire_month:11, termenPornire_day:1, documentPath:, tema:Promotie A, termenLimita_day:1, _action_savenew:Adauga2, id:, observatii:uuu, termenLimita:date.struct, termenPornire_year:2012, etapa.id:1, etapa:[id:1], contact.id:1, contact:[id:1], termenPornire:date.struct, firma:Google, idActiune:zt8h, termenLimita_year:2012, action:save, controller:actiune]
\
**....**

in save...       [user:Flavian, termenPornire:Thu Nov 01 22:57:45 EET 2012, contact:null, documentPath:null, temaId:1, etapaId:null, firmaId:3, firma:Google, contactId:null, termenLimita:null, idActiune:zt8h, observatii:null, userId:null, etapa:null, tema:Promotie A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `actiuneInstance.validate()` and then look at the [`actiuneInstance.errors` object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html) to see the result of any validation errors on your object.